# Attempting to write code to search a list of words for words with atleast two double letters

Tags: python, list

```
def three_doubles(s):
      for i in range(0, len(s)-5);
        if s[i] = s[i+1] and s[i+2] == s[i+3] and s[i+4] == s[i+5]:
          return True
       return False
```

Trying to modify this code to search for words with atleast two consecutive double letters

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand exactly what you've asked.

```
l=['asd','aabb','ccddee']
for w in l:
    if len(w)>1:
        if len(w)==(2*len(set(w))):
            print w
```

Comment: @user2117024
is that what you want?